# How can I check whether rsync transfered files or not?

Tags: linux, cygwin, rsync

I use rsync (cygwin) to transfer files between server and my PC.

Rsync runs every 2 minutes, and sometimes there are some files to transfer, sometimes not. I need to execute some actions, but only if files were transferred from server to PC.

How do I know, whether files were transferred or not?

P.S. I tried to use rsync's exit codes, but it returns 0 in both when files are transfered and when they don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rsync -rtv <source> <dest> | wc -l
```

If the result is more than 4 something changed

Comment: Thank you, that works great :) Can you explain what number 4 means?

Comment: `wc -l` counts the number of lines . A clean run with option `-v` have 4 lines in the output. Any change has more than 4

Comment: This is what is referred to as programming by side-effect and a really undesirable and brittle way to solve this problem. A better solution would be to use a --log-file or --stats flags as mentioned in answers below.

Comment: @JoshEnders in general you are right. But if Rsync coders change the output of `-rtv`  or of `--stats` processing the output will have the same problem. I would not use the `--log` as it is additive and processing the log could be an overkill for simple scope.

Answer (score 4):

### `rsync --stats`

You can use the option `--stats` or `--info=stats2` eventually filtering with a grep.

```
  rsync -avr ORIG DEST  --stats | grep "Number of created files"
```

> Number of **created files: 14**

---

From the manual of `rsync` you can read

> **--stats**
>    This  tells rsync to print **a verbose set of statistics** on the file transfer, allowing you to tell how effective rsync’s delta-transfer algorithm is for your data.  This option is equivalent to --info=stats2 if combined with 0 or 1 -v options, or --info=stats3 if combined with 2 or more -v options.

**Further notes:**
 I suggest you to use a logfile as [proposed](https://superuser.com/a/1095722/257269) by MariusMatutiae in case you will have *the curiosity* to see which files were transferred.
For the `grep` filter you can choose each line that you find interesting:

- **Example of output with some file transferred:**

  > Number of files: 15 (reg: 14, dir: 1)
  >   **Number of created files: 14 (reg: 14)**
  >   Number of deleted files: 0
  >   **Number of regular files transferred: 14**
  >   Total file size: 280,860 bytes
  >   **Total transferred file size: 280,860 bytes**
  >   Literal data: 280,860 bytes
  >   Matched data: 0 bytes
  >   File list size: 0
  >   File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
  >   File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
  >   Total bytes sent: 281,842
  >   Total bytes received: 285
- **The same command with no file transferred:**

  > Number of files: 15 (reg: 14, dir: 1)
  >   **Number of created files: 0**
  >   **Number of deleted files: 0**
  >   **Number of regular files transferred: 0**
  >   Total file size: 280,860 bytes
  >   **Total transferred file size: 0 bytes**
  >   Literal data: 0 bytes
  >   Matched data: 0 bytes
  >   File list size: 0
  >   File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
  >   File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
  >   Total bytes sent: 357
  >   Total bytes received: 12

Answer (score 3):

I use the option

```
 rsync ....  --log-file=/path/to/log/file
```

This **adds** to the log-file, so you can find out whether anything at all has been transferred, and, if so, what exactly, even much later than when the backup took place.

Comment: yep, i already use --log-file and what if i need to pass file names to the script? Guess i have to use awk or sed to extract them from log file and that seems a bit tricky to me )

Comment: they are for me. Besides, it was preferable to solve this using just rsync's options.

Comment: @temur_p Just for the record: `--log-file` **is** an option of `rsync`'s.

Comment: I was talking about using `awk or sed`. It seems like you didnt understand the problem - if i'm gonna use `--log-file`, then i'll have to extract file names from it by using `awk or sed`. And by using solution, proposed in first message, i can simply handle the problem by adding `if` condition.

Comment: When I do this, I use `mktemp` to come up with a name for them log file (`$LOGFILE`), then
`if grep -q ">f" "$LOGFILE"; then
  echo stuff has been transferred
fi`
also `grep ">f" "$LOGFILE" | cut -f5- -d\  `
will extract transferred filenames from the log. awk and sed are unnecessary sledgehammers here.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a more strict solution. I don't want to grep for `Number of created files:` (the message could be in another language) or remove all lines but two in `-v` output (who knows what summary `rsync` will print in the next version?).

I found that you can set the format of a `rsync`'s log, but not the format of its stdout (see [`man rsyncd.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyncd.conf)).

For example, add a "File changed!" to each line with an actually changed file, and then `grep` for it:

```
rsync -a \
    --log-file=/tmp/rsync.log \
    --log-file-format="File changed! %f %i" \
    source-dir target-dir

if fgrep "File changed!" /tmp/rsync.log > /dev/null; then
    echo "rsync did something!"
fi
```

One problem with this approach is that it doesn't work with `--dry-run`. In this case, one has to add `--itemize-changes` and parse the stdout; and you cannot set its format.

Answer (score 0):

This is a brittle solution, but I really don't like running rsync in a subshell, nor capturing its output, both have made things difficult for me to debug in the past.

So when I need this, what I do is compare the output of `ls -la "$target"` before and after calling rsync.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).